# How to do multiple grep pattern to find value in grepped string

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to do multiple grep pattern to find a number within a grepped string.

I have a text file like this:

```
This is the first sample line 1
this is the second sample line
another line

total lines: 3 tot
```

I am trying to find a way to get just the number of total lines. So the output here should be "3"

Here are the things I've tried:

```
grep "total lines: [0-9]" myfile.txt
grep "total lines" myfile.txt | grep "[0-9]"
```

Comment: `grep "total lines: [0-9]*" myfile.txt | cut -d ' ' -f3`

Comment: With GNU grep: `grep -Po "total lines: \K[0-9]*" myfile.txt` will do the trick

Comment: @Jetchisel : The astersik is not necessary here, since `cut` gets the whole line anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed -En 's/^total lines: ([0-9]+).*/\1/p' myfile.txt
```

- `-E` extended regular expressions
- `-n` suppress automatic printing
- Match `^total lines: ([0-9]+).*` (capture the number)
- `\1` replace the whole line with the captured number
- `p` print the result

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** Using GNU `grep` try following. Simply using `-o` option to print only matched value, `-P` enables PCRE regex for program. Then in regex portion matching from starting `^total lines:`  in each line and if a match found then discard matched values by `\K` option(to remove it from expected output) which is followed by 1 or more digits, using positive look ahead to make sure its followed by space(s) tot here.

```
grep -oP '^total lines: \K[0-9]+(?=\s+tot)' Input_file
```

---

***2nd solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following in `awk`. This could be done in a single `awk` itself. Searching line which has string `/total lines: /` in it then printing 2nd last field of that line.

```
awk '/total lines: /{print $(NF-1)}' Input_file
```

---

***3rd solution:*** Using `awk`'s `match` function here. Matching `total lines: [0-9]+ tot` and then substituting everything apart from digits with null in matched values.

```
awk 'match($0,/total lines: [0-9]+ tot/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"",val);print val}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use grep?

```
$ echo myfile.txt | wc -l
```

If you mean that the file has a line in it formatted as

> total lines: 3 tot

Then refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/can-grep-output-only-specified-groupings-that-match and use something like:

```
grep -Po 'total lines: \K\d+' myfile.txt
```

Notes:

1. Perl regex is not my forte, so the \d\w part might not work.
2. This may be doable without -P, but I cannot test from this windows computer.
3. regex101.com helped me test the above line, so it may work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with relying on *pattern* of last line and applying grep/sed to find pattern is that if any line in file contains such pattern, then you will have to apply some additional logic to filter that.
e.g. Consider case of below input file.

```
line001
total lines: 883 tot
This is the first sample line 1
this is the second sample line
another line

total lines: 883 tot
```

Assuming your file format is constant (i.e. Second last line will be blank and last line will contain total count), instead of using any pattern matching commands you can directly count number of rows using below **awk** command.

```
awk 'END { print NR - 2 }' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `awk` to get the third field on a line that starts with `total count:` and stop processing the file further:

```sh
awk '/^total lines:/{print $3; exit}' file
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/PUwRPY).

You can use the following GNU `grep`:

```sh
# Extract a non-whitespace chunk after a certain pattern
grep -oP '^total lines:\s*\K\S+' file

# Extract a number after a pattern
grep -oP '^total lines:\s*\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?' file
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/CPbExn). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `total lines:` - a literal string
- `\s*` - any zero or more whitespace chars
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - one or more digits and then an optional sequence of `.` and one or more digits.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/W88Eyg/1).